# Can't connect to azure mysql server in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, mysql, remote, azure

I have an Azure virtual machine holding an Ubuntu system, with MySQL server and I want to access the database from a web application.
When I installed mysql-server, I executed

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

to allow tcp connections. 
In the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` I added `bind-address = 168.63.178.87`, which is the "Virtual IP Address" that Azure panel tells me.

In mysql, the user I am using to connect has all privileges on the database needed (I think):

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@%                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pass_ommited' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'%'                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when the application tries to connect to the database, I recieve the error:

```
 CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '168.63.178.87' (4)
```

(It's a Yii framework application, in case it matters).

I have full SSH access to the virtual machine, using the given IP address and a specific port. 
Azure also tells me the "Internal IP address", which is `10.78.28.85`.
I have tried binding the MySQL server to that address and to `0.0.0.0`, but none has worked.

I suspect the problem is the redirection made to access my specific instance in the server, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved it.
The problem was that I didn't have an endpoint in Azure.

I have created the endpoint with the `3306` port and restarted mysql-server with `sudo restart mysql`

Other mistake I had is that I needed to set the bind address as the Internal IP Address of the server.

Comment: Other mistake I had is that I needed to set the bind address as the Internal IP Address of the server. how do I bind on a Windows Box?

Comment: In my case, binding to the internal IP address worked.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint is not enough! Just spent 4 hours solving this problem.
You also need to verify that your server has a firewall rule for MySql port, and most importantly, the rule is PUBLIC:

[image: as shown here]